# SQLCODE=-501 SQLSTATE=24501 with Cursor

Tags: db2

I have written a stored procedure as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROC1()
DECLARE VAR1 INT;
DECLARE VAR2 INT;
DECLARE TEXT VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE exitcode INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR WITH HOLD for STMT1 ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET exitcode = 1;

SET TEXT= (-----);
PREPARE STMT1 FROM TEXT; 

open cur1;
fetch from cur1 into var1,var2;
while(sqlcode =0)
do
--
--
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE emp1 ');

set exit code = 0;
fetch from cur1 into var1,var2;
IF (exitcode = 1)
       THEN
       LEAVE wloop;
     END IF; 
end while; 
close cur1;
```

My question is even I declared my cursor as WITH HOLD option, after the first fetch the cursor is closing & throwing -501 error.If i remove the REORG statement from the loop. Then cursor is working normally,fetching all the rows. Can some one tel me the way to keep my cursor to be open even If i use the REORG statement inside the loop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Uh, your cursor doesn't do anything....  If it touches `emp1`, then it's probably closing the cursor because you changed the table it was looking at.  You shouldn't be re-orging in a loop in the first place (it has the potential to be a really long-running operation).  Also - anything above `0` means "success with a warning" (like, say, no rows affected, statement plan re-evaluated, etc); whether or not you want to continue depends on if you care about the specific warning...

Comment: As per the post at http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1671145-reorg-is-a-cursor-killer, Knut Stolze (an IBM research guy) said REORG executes a ROLLBACK internally and this behaviour is expected. He also suggested an alternative approach.